# Which preposition should be used in "building of/with 100 storeys"

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct preposition here:

> building **of\with** 100 storeys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefer **a building with 100 storeys** to **a building of 100 storeys**.

Although both are possible, far more likely is **a 100-storey building**.